# Water Pump Pressure Switch Adjustment

Tags: water-pressure

Hi we have a water pump in our building i wanted to change its cut in and cut off pressures but i couldn't understand pressure switch's setting also there is pressure gauge but i think it's not functioning correctly because i couldn't find a pattern on that this is a picture of the pressure switch i want to know what is it's current pressure range ty
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current setting is to pump up to 90 psi and shut off. When the pressure drops to 45 it will turn back on and pump to 90. If you wand a more even pressure reduce the differential pressure. Reducing the differential to 20 the pressure will stay between 90 & 70. this will cause the pump to cycle more often than its current settings. If the pump is cycling rapidly the pressure tank may have lost its air charge.

Comment: thank you for your answer so if i want to change dif or range i just have to turn off the pump and screw these ?http://uupload.ir/files/qvvs_dsc_0422.jpg

Comment: Yes take the silver screw and lock plate off to make the adjustment. When done replace the plate. (The plate keeps the screws from moving while running)